# Which browser APIs does amp-script allow custom JavaScript to access?

Tags: javascript, amp-html, web-worker, navigator

Now that we have `<amp-script>` which allows custom, third-party JavaScript to run on AMP pages, I'm trying to determine whether I still have access to the same info I collect right now on non-AMP pages. E.g. user agent. I have the following example, where I have this code on the page:

```
<amp-script layout="container" src="/javascripts/alert.js">
  Output message: <span id="outputMsg"></span>
</amp-script>
```

And I have the this code in the retrieved JS file:

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log('XHR ctor works');

const collectedData = {
    userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
};
console.log('user agent accessible')

document.cookie = "key=value";
console.log('cookie set works');

document.getElementById('outputMsg').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(collectedData, null, 4);
console.log('DOM mutation works');
```

The idea is that this would tell me what code is allowed to run under the conditions imposed by `<amp-script>`. I get the following output in the console:

```
Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1905021827420 http://localhost:3000/search?searchterm=diamond
/javascripts/alert.js:32 XHR ctor works
/javascripts/alert.js:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/javascripts/alert.js:35)
    at /javascripts/alert.js:45
```

So I can see that some things are allowed and some aren't. I was able to rearrange that code to determine that the only thing in that example that wasn't allowed was accessing the `navigator` object.

Is there an allowlist of things AMP pages are allowed to do using `<amp-script>`? I looked in their official docs and was not able to find this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `<amp-script>` is powered by [WorkerDOM](https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom), the best place to look into this is the WorkerDOM documentation.

Specifically, there is a [WorkerDOM compatibility](https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/master/web_compat_table.md) table where you can see which APIs are currently available.

When it comes to the `navigator` object, this should be supported via [WorkerNavigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator). Try using `self.navigator.userAgent` instead and this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I didn't realize it would be as simple as checking WorkerDOM features. I ended up moving in a different direction but this is still good to know.